# filter results quarterly

Tags: c#, filter

I am writing a simple C# application that is handling bank savings.
I want to be able to show the results on either, yearly, monthly or quarterly basic how can this be done? How can I loop through a set of results and only show every third post (if I am using quarterly) for example.

In Python I can use `range(1,31,3)` but how is it done in C#?

**UPDATE 1**

I want to loop 12 times (annually) and calculate the interest each loop but I only want to print the results every third loop (quarterly). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may also consider using a compound interest formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only show every third item?

```
for (int i = startingItem; i < list.Count; i += 3)
{
    // show list[i]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I have correctly understood the question, but if you want for instance every 3 days, you could use this expression :

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Where(e => e % 3 == 0);
```

It returns the following values :

```
3 
6 
9 
12 
15 
18 
21 
24 
27 
30
```

Edit :

> I want to loop 12 times (annually) and
>   calculate the interest each loop but I
>   only want to print the results every
>   third loop. How can I achive this?

You can simply loop from 1 to 12, and if you want to print every 3 loops, just look at this sample.  The `sum` variable holds the grand total.

```
int sum=0;

foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 12))
{
    int tmp = i;
    sum += DoYourCalculation(tmp);
    if (tmp % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done in SQL, assuming you are using a database, using [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/l/aacuberollup.htm) or similar.

Comment: I am not using a database, only arrays and such.

Comment: @user339067 - That would be your first problem, don't use arrays and 'such' to store bank savings account information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us much to work with here... what sort of data structures do you have? A database? A list? An array?

You could do this simple in a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 12; i+=3) {...}
```

This would hit every third month, assuming you had one record per month. Though, quarterly results are usually the *sum* of the past 3 months, are they not (well, it might be more complicated than that)? So it might not be enough to *disply* the 3rd item, you might have to go through 3 items, display the sum of them for that quarter, go through the next 3 items, display the sum, etc...

...I'd attempt a solution with LINQ if I were better with it. ;)

**Edit**

to sum up 3 numbers in the array and display them:

```
int sum;
for (int i =1; i<= 12; i+=3)
{
    //just make sure you don't go beyond the bounds of your array!
    sum = someArray[i]+someArray[i+1]+someArray[i+2];
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Alternate:

```
int sum;
for (int i =1; i<= 12; i++)
{
    sum += someArray[i];
    if (i%3==0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        sum =0;
    }
}
```

...There are many other ways to do this. I haven't compiled these so I don't know 100% that they're what you want, but they should put you on the right track.

Comment: "you might have to go through 3 items, display the sum of them for that quarter, go through the next 3 items, display the sum". Yes, this is exactly what I need. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [Shimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046599/c-filter-results-quarterly/3046653#3046653) said you could do this...

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * 3);
```

... it would have the advantage of not creating the values you are going to skip anyway.

If you want more power with LINQ you could create yourself something like this (the advantage being that could process an infinite set of numbers [well almost infinite, this would use `int` so it would overflow at `int.MaxValue`]...

```
public static class EnumerableCounters
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Counter()
    {
        return Counter(0);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<int> Counter(int offset)
    {
        return Counter(offset, 1);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<int> Counter(int offset, int step)
    {
        for (var x = offset; ; x += step)
            yield return x;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vals = EnumerableCounters.Counter(10, 3).Take(5).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to process every value, and want to do something special for every third value, you will need to test the loop variable inside the loop to detect that interval.  Some of the other solutions handled the every third value, but not the every value case.  Something like this should do, substitute your actual logic as needed for ProcessMonth and ProcessQuarter.

```
for(int numMonth = 0; numMonth < 12; numMonth++)
{
     ProcessMonth(balance[numMonths]);
     if ((numMonth + 1) % 3 == 0)
     {
          ProcessQuarter(numMonth);
     }
}
```